# How to refer a cell data into countifs formula?

Tags: excel

My excel image:

[image]

At E6 cell, I used this formula:

```
=countifs(Example1!$L$19:$L$1000;$B$6;Exampale1!$M$19:$M$1000;$C$6)
```

And at F6 cell, i used this formula with C8 cell contains the sheetname that I want to refer:

```
=countifs('INDIRECT(C8)'!$L$19:$L$1000;$B$6;'INDIRECT(C8)'!$M$19:$M$1000;$C$6)
```

why are there 2 different returned results?

As expected, I want F6 will return as E6.

I tried to search but nothing can resolve.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how indirect works.

Replace the formula in F6 as follow.

`=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&C8&"'!"&"$L$19:$L$1000"),$B$6,INDIRECT("'"&C8&"'!"&"$M$19:$M$1000"),$C$6)`

Comment: thank you very much but i still get Error message after using your formula :( 
here is my excel file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/125McspuTc46N5hLt7y2gz-D8j2G9Ol5Sb4EKViZ3fqw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: thank a lot for your help. Base on your answer, i fixed my formula as below and it work well:
=countifs(INDIRECT("'"&C8&"'!$L$19:$L$1000");$B$6;INDIRECT("'"&C8&"'!$M$19:$M$1000");$C$6)

Comment: ! symbol and the range were intentionally kept separate as I assumed the scenarios where your ranges may vary.